# Error Key column doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando crear 2 tablas y una de ellas tiene una llave foranea, no sé que estoy haciendo mal, pero devuelve este error: Key column doesn't exist in table.

```
CREATE TABLE Propietario(
 Cedula VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
 Nombre VARCHAR(255),
 Direccion VARCHAR(255),
 Fecha_Nacimiento Datetime,
 Genero VARCHAR(11));

CREATE TABLE Auto(
 Placa VARCHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY,
 Cedula_Propietario VARCHAR(20),
 Marca VARCHAR(255),
 Anio Datetime,
 Num_Pasajerons INT,
 Cilindraje FLOAT,
FOREIGN KEY (Cedula_Propietario) REFERENCES Propietario(Cedula));
```

Comment: Que manejador de BD estas usando? Probe online acá (https://paiza.io/projects/4TI-9-pmS0UxLOmOd2nwdw) y no me genera ningún error

Comment: Tu script se ejecuta sin problemas en http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d86f9

Comment: estoy usando mysql con mysqlworkbench, efectivamente solo falla en el gestor desde MacOs. ¿Alguna idea de por qué sucede esto solamente en mi local?

Comment: TIene pinta de tener algún lío con el CamelCase. Prueba creando las tablas con los nombres en _lowercase_.